# Jquery Ajax Get - Large XML File Hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a large XML file 500 000 lines, 9mb.

This is a parsed down version. I could reduce some white space, but will not be able to make this file much smaller.

The problem I am having is I want to display this in a grid in my web browser, but can't seem to retrieve the file. It appears to hang.

I am currently making a simple .get request, and using jquery to parse xml.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("test1");
        $.get("../../XML/events.xml", function (data) {
            console.log("tests2");
            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc),
            $test= $xml.find("Event").Size();
            console.log($test);
        });          
    });
</script>
```

At this point, I am hitting the first console log. "test1", but not "test2".

I'm looking at my network tab in my dev tools, and see that a successful get is being made. 
[image: Request/Response is successful...]

I'm not sure why this is not working. I've tried a different file, and it works fine.
Is there a max file size?
Is this just to slow for the jq library?
Is it a browser issues?

Any thoughts? 
Note** This is for personal use, and is not leaving my localhost, so performance /usability is not an issue.

Comment: try using $.ajax with dataType as xml, and put both a success and error function

Comment: huge file = long time to parse